# Why is this code saying Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, lookup

I am trying to create a string build function called `addToCache` and the parameters of the function is defined by an interface called `Payloads`

So based on the key code of the string registered from an `enum` called `MyStringsTest`, Typescript should perform a type lookup using that key code.

```
export enum MyStringsTest {
    DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE='DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE',
    A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR='A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR',
}
export interface Payloads {
    [MyStringsTest.DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE]: number,
    [MyStringsTest.A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR]: string,
}
const cache:{ [K in keyof Payloads]?: (payload: Payloads[K]) => string } = {}
function addToCache<K extends keyof Payloads>(code: K, cb: ((payload: Payloads[K]) => string)): void{
    cache[code] = cb // I have the error here Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
}
addToCache(MyStringsTest.DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE, (data) => `Depart in ${data} minutes!`);
addToCache(MyStringsTest.A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR, (data) => `a driver is asking for ${data}`);
```

It looks like the usage works but the compiler shows this error

`Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'` I tried to understand why but I can't find the reason

This is the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwLIE8DKMoCWiA5gM4Aqwp8A3gLABQczcAIgKIAKAggErkB9AJIA5AQA0BGUQFVy7ALwByDj37Cxk6SLnslAGkYs43Aa15CAau17CcA7jgDSogOICAYgHley0%20asbOwdnN08fA0YAX0ZQSFg4IhhgKAAzAEMAY2A4TnSsABsIdIATUjh6JhYAbWw8QhIKKhgAOlU%20QVEJKVl5AF0ALjgUVAAjFMMq5lrcfCIySmoW-wtrWyF7RxcRd29eQbhqBuJJmIZMiERqOEysgAtgAZo4aqdExDgAa2AsCFTc-JFUqkPoAfiGAAowIDiiUhnlCrDSK8%20gBKOAKAB8hzmJDgUQxFTOqWQiEyMAIlzgpRK5AgAGF7sAADxvUDJRBlL4-P4AxHAzEQi4lR5wJz6G6jSFQmGleGysoo9FYnHHVGooYANwgBBKlWMt0yD2qwuAfUJmVG0UYNLpjKNwAhdVxC2abS4HQ03W0uglEJK6Rg6WV2IABqxgNCEkQ4AASGgBoME1BEZDJUgAQlDqIA3DaSrSGUynbNjk0litAutNqEduFeH7E8GMWH0nASoRNSlEuV0qRPvM4KloHGE4H0lFs3mGEA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helping typescript a little by creating separate type alias for cache works just fine!

```js
export enum MyStringsTest {
  DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE = 'DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE',
  A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR = 'A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR'
}
export interface Payloads {
  [MyStringsTest.DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE]: number
  [MyStringsTest.A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR]: string
}

type Catch = {
  [K in keyof Payloads]?: (payload: Payloads[K]) => string
}

const cache: Catch = {}
function addToCache<K extends keyof Catch>(code: K, cb: Catch[K]): void {
  cache[code] = cb
}
addToCache(MyStringsTest.DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE, (data) => `Depart in ${data} minutes!`)
addToCache(MyStringsTest.A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR, (data) => `a driver is asking for ${data}`)
```

Bdw do you really need enum, you could very well get rid of that completely as follows

```js
export interface Payloads {
  DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE: number
  A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR: string
}

type Catch = {
  [K in keyof Payloads]?: (payload: Payloads[K]) => string
}

const cache: Catch = {}
function addToCache<K extends keyof Catch>(code: K, cb: Catch[K]): void {
  cache[code] = cb
}

addToCache('DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE', (data) => `Depart in ${data} minutes!`)
addToCache('A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR', (data) => `a driver is asking for ${data}`)
```

Comment: thank you so much. it works, but I don understand why, Please help me one last time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865609/why-is-this-code-saying-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-never  It is the same question follow up