# Why is this code saying Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Why is the code below saying `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'` ?

However, the compiled javascript works perfectly fine

```
export enum MyStringsTest {
    DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE='DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE',
    A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR='A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR',
}
export interface Payloads {
    [MyStringsTest.DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE]: number,
    [MyStringsTest.A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR]: string,
}

type Cache = {
  [K in keyof Payloads]?: (payload: Payloads[K]) => string
}

const cache: Cache = {}
function addToCache<K extends keyof Cache>(code: K, cb: (Cache[K])): void{
    cache[code] = cb
}
addToCache(MyStringsTest.DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE, (data) => `Depart in ${data} minutes!`);
addToCache(MyStringsTest.A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR, (data) => `a driver is asking for ${data}`);

function getParsed<T extends keyof Cache>(stringCode: T, payload: Payloads[T]) {
    const builder = cache[stringCode]
    const ans = builder(payload as any) // <- error here
    return ans;
}

getParsed(MyStringsTest.A_DRIVER_IS_ASKING_FOR, 'a sandwitch')
getParsed(MyStringsTest.DEPART_IN_X_MINUTE, 456)
// This prints "a driver is asking for a sandwitch"
// This prints "Depart in 456 minutes!"
```

Its a follow up to [Why is this code saying Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865211/why-is-this-code-saying-type-number-is-not-assignable-to-type-never#63865425)

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwLIE8DKMoCWiA5gM4Aqwp8A3gLABQczcAIgKIAKAggErkB9AJIA5AQA0BGUQFVy7ALwByDj37Cxk6SLnslAGkYs43Aa15CAau17CcA7jgDSogOICAYgHley0%20asbOwdnN08fA0YAX0ZQSFg4IhhgKAAzAEMAY2A4TnSsABsIdIATUjh6JhYAbWw8QhIKKhgAOlU%20QVEJKVl5AF0ALjgUVAAjFMMq5lrcfCIySmoW-wtrWyF7RxcRd29eQbhqBuJJmIZGGCwwHIBhLIALHIUKozhqp0TEOABrYCwIVK5fJFUqkPoAfiGAAowMDiiUhnlCvDSO8%20gBKOAKAB8hzmJGijEYmQgiGocEyD2AQzumUeWIqZ1SyEQmRgBFJcFKJXIEFpjwAPB9QMlEGUfn8AXB%20cBsVCSSVqXAnPoKaNoTK0ej0UMAG4QAglSrGSl04DVBXAPoMzKjQkMbm8mVQur4hbNNpcDoabraXSqqEldIwdKYnFwAAGrGAsISRDgABIaEGQ1E4KgiMhkqQAIQR9EAbkYjr5VJds2OTSWK0C602oR24V4AZToaxuIj6TgJUIupSiXK6VI33mcFS0ETyeD6Si%20aL5wYzNZ7M5xGAMDyUFIwBKAvICBAovFv3%20gJlcqO8xuEEVQ3IqthyNKiLhoOq5AxLymFNJ5NGyAIApFSgG0qWqS8SGvRU%20leZgSTJeB0jJBl-0A4CYVfEpMQAemwuABQAWgQKAoAnR4oByWC4AomBkCgL4kNIeczkYNcN3SLcd3Lep5irVoazWYItjCPZVSUAAWABWAA2JR0UYXC4HIe4CHKMAGhgcoACIux7Ag%20xA1SuWHUdxxAqTpK0oA)

Comment: Have you tried adding the return type to that function? looks like you want to return a string I think, but your function has no return type there.

Comment: `cache[stringCode] as (payload: Payloads[T]) => string` does "help" TypeScript to realise that the type of `builder` depends on `T`. (Btw `builder` could be `undefined` according to the type `Cache`, you might want to revisit that `?`).

Comment: Thank you! I would appreciate if you can explain why do I need to "help" typescript in this scenario.

Comment: @TSR I believe [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) is the relevant issue